# jquery autocomplete in ASP not working

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

I have googled for this and I am not an expert on it either. I tried the following code thinking I am doing it right to implement a simple autocomplete textbox. But does not work. Here is the code. If anyone would help out what could be wrong with it, that will be a big help. My textbox simply does not return any autocomplete suggestions when I try it.

Thanks.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="jquery.WebForm1" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <%--<link href="jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />--%>
        <title></title>
        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" 
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>  
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#TextBox1").autocomplete
               ({
                   source: ["Joe", "John", "Jack", "Ben", "Bell", "Steve", "Scott"]  // simple list of strings 
               });


            });
        </script>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

            <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reference for jquery ui library in ur code

TRY TO ADD THIS :

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```